# Ability to disabled a Quick Action Lightning Button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-quickaction

Tried searching for this but was not able to find a definitive answer. I don't think it's possible as I've been trying, but can I disable a quick action button in lightning experience.

I have a quick action that is linked to a lightning component. I have a doInit but that doesn't seem to take affect unless I actually click on the button.

Essentially when the page loads without having to do anything based on certain conditions I would like for the quick action button to be disabled. Is this possible? From various testing and search this does not seem to be the case. Thank you.

Comment: We can't hide a quick action, but we can create multiple page layouts to show/hide the quick action buttons based on the data we have for the current record.

Answer (score 2):

Hope, you've created a quick action button with Lightning Component.

Lightning component will be fired only on button click. You cannot disable a quick action. Instead you can throw some message from your doInit function if the conditions are not met.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your issue I would use ui:button.

```
<ui:button label="test" aura:id="myButton"/>
```

And in doInit call something like this:

```
({ doInit : function(component, event, helper) { 
var button = component.find("myButton"); 
$A.util.addClass(button.getElement(), 'slds-hide');})
```

And after conditions to show this button would be met:

```
$A.util.addClass(button.getElement(), 'slds-show');
```

Answer (score 0):

i m not much familiar to lightning but if you are talking to hide fuctionality of cancel save llike buttons you can use

`showQuickActionVfHeader=false`

Comment: We implement this to hide the quick action modal button, no to disable the quick action button which loads the lightning component inside the modal with the cancel button.